# Possibility of conditional sentence for the future?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Firstly, would you correct me if I'm wrong?

> Were we to meet again, ~

This implies the meeting will never happen in the future, like "If I meet you in the heaven". 0 percent possibilities.

> Should we cross over again, ~

This implies the meeting will less likely to happen. Like 25(?) percent of possibilities

> If I see you again, ~

This has purely 50/50 chances to meet them each other.

Secondly, then what should I use for the probable future conditional like above 50% possibilities. Do I just add some adverbs like "If I possibly see you again"?

Comment: Could you substantiate your conclusions? I think all of them indicate some possibility. The likelihood depends more on the overall context that the wording of the phrases themselves.

Answer (score -1):

All 3 of those examples imply that the event still could happen (including the first example). But to answer your second question, there is really no way to imply a greater chance than using "if" (aside from "when I see you again", which implies a 100% chance).